# hot added vCPU for linux not used fully in top command

Tags: linux, debian, vmware-vsphere, cpu-usage, top

just recently we started to see high CPU pressure on one of our machines. 
All our machines are running Linux Debian and we use vmware under the hood.

We have hot added new CPUs and they're online in the system `echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/online`

However when we use top to check new CPUs the new ones are not as busy as the other ones. Check the screenshot.

[image: top command showing old CPUs and new ones not getting same amount of load]

As you can see in the image, previous CPUs are getting between 15-24 however new ones are just doing almost nothing.

We've seen this in some other occasions and a reboot usually fix this issue, so after reboot new CPUs get load as the other ones.

We'd like to know if it's possible to not need a reboot in order to get new CPUs at fully load.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the software you are using decides how many processes to execute only at startup and in practice doesn't notice there are new cores available. You can probably restart only the application and not the entire machine. Maybe you should provide more information about the software you are using. It could also be a configuration parameter for the software on how many threads/processes to run. Definitely more information on the software will help.

Comment: I didn't mention it because I thought it was more a linux thing, but you are right, that machine is a node for a Kubernetes cluster v1.7.3. 

So maybe the best option is to move this question directly to Kubernetes guys.

Thanks @krasi, for pointing me in that direction.